# tankless electric hot water heater

Tags: electrical

I had a rheem retex-13 (13kw) electric hot water heater installed and it requires 60-A breaker and it was put on a 2 pole double 30-A can I switch that with a 2 pole double 60-A?

Comment: That depends on (a) whether your panel can handle it and (b) whether your wires can handle it. Post a picture of your panel, plus closeups on the existing breaker/wires and also the wires where they are connected to the heater.

Comment: my electrical panel is full it has 2/ 2-pole 30-A over each other one is for the dryer and they used the other one for the tankless

Comment: Look at code the proper answer is NO I do not have a code book as I am in the field but electric heating is limited and 60 is beyond the limit so they split it. It’s been code for decades.

Comment: the tankless water heater I bought requires a 60-A breaker what can I do? the hot water heater that was taken out was run off a 2-pole 30-A breaker so they ran the tankless off the same one but it kept on tripping the breaker so I bought 2 new 2-pole 30-A breakers

Comment: or can I a single 60-A breaker?

Comment: @EdBeal Specs have the 13kW using 1 60A 240V breaker - see https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/a8/a8533f9b-7fcd-4870-87de-ff1f0aec8a96.pdf Larger sizes bump up to multiple 40A circuits.

Comment: the original wire was switched with a 6AWG wire

Comment: What make and model is your electric panel, and can you post a photo of it showing which position the water heater breaker is in?

Comment: How does the water heater's manual tell you to wire it?  Does it tell you to use dual 30A circuits, or are you just freestylin'?

Comment: I did finally have a chance to check 424.22 48a  with a 60 amp breaker but since the MFG instructions said the same they would override the code that was not in the original question. I mostly do gas and heat pumps we don’t get in the negative numbers so emergency heat is not normally needed here most use wood stoves or pellet heat in my area because wood is plentiful.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the existing breaker please @bill?

Comment: It depends on what the mfg states! If the total requirement is 2 ea 30 amp double pole breakers it is legal and more common in 40+ amp or 80 total breakers even 3 in parallel is allowed by code and even required with large electric heated homes (ok I have done 4 parallel on a almost 6000sf all electric house) so this is the difference in ideal and real code /mfg requirements.

Answer (score -1):

### That would be *paralleling*. You can't do that.

Certainly, 120/240V split-phase can be confusing to the novice.  But when an amperage is stated, such as 60A, that always means exactly what it says -- you never halve or double it because of the split-phase.

Being a 240V breaker/circuit merely means it has 2 poles instead of 1.
"120V per pole" is actually how you think of it, but again, never multiply/divide.
So for instance it would have been acceptable to use two *120V* 60A breakers and handle-tie them... (of course 60A 120V breakers are not made, but if they were; yes).

The only possible way to make two 2-pole 30A breakers work would be a cobbled-together version of paralleling... the paralleling rules are quite narrow and don't allow anything like that, for a variety of reasons.  Paralleling equipment is really special.